# MultiLingual Site in Zend Framework 2 - set value of setLocale() from URL param

Tags: php, zend-framework2, translation, multilingual

Below is what I have done so far -

In **`Application Module - module.config.php`** -

```
'service_manager' => array(
    [....],
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern' => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

In **`Album Module - module.config.php`** -

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '[/:lang]/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'lang' => '[a-zA-Z]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

In **`Album Module - Module.php`** -

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $router = $sm->get('router');
    $request = $sm->get('request');
    $matchedRoute = $router->match($request);
    $params = $matchedRoute->getParams();

    if(isset($params['lang']) && $params['lang'] !== '') {
        $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        //or
        //$translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('MvcTranslator');

        if($params['lang'] == 'en')
            $translator->setLocale('en_US');
        elseif($params['lang'] == 'fr')
            $translator->setLocale('fr_FR');
        else
            $translator->setLocale('en_US');
    }
}
```

In **`view`** -

```
echo $this->translate('Home');
```

Note: URL - **`http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/fr/album`, works just fine.** The translation is successful.

---

**Query -**

`$translator->setLocale('en');` seems to be working with ZF1 but not with ZF2.

I need to know whether there is any way to directly set the URL param value like `$translator->setLocale($params['lang']);` rather then long `if-else` or `switch` statements.

Some sites might be in 20 or more languages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: use [SlmLocale](http://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmLocale). I wrote the module to implement locale detection DRY and for different use cases.

Don't try to fit the localization into your routes. This allows you to have translatable routes as you detect the locale before routing. Also, it helps you enormously to change locale with different URIs.

A mistake you made in your process is that you grab the route match from the event during bootstrap. However, bootstrap occurs before routing, so you can't get the route match parameters at that stage.

TL;DR: checkout SlmLocale, it should help you with all your problems.

Comment: I will definitely look into the `SlmLocale` module. I have already mentioned in the question that the above code is working fine. I am getting the value of `lang` from params in `onBootstrap` as `fr`, when the url is `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/fr/album` and translation is working. I will let you know how it turns out with your module. Thanks again.

Comment: I have implemented your module and it inserts `en-US` as the first segment to the URL. But what I want is that the translation to be made to the content in the pages when I have the URL as `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/fr/album`. That is, translation to `French` as my URL has `fr` in it.